# how to display checkin table in one row

Tags: php, mysql, format

I have a table that looks like this.

```
pers_id pers_name   pers_date   pers_date_attend_ind
431        Bacon    1/14/2013   N
431        Bacon    1/27/2013   N
431        Bacon    1/28/2013   N
431        Bacon    2/17/2013   N
```

I'd like to display it in php like

```
        <date 1>    <date 2>   <Date 3>
Bacon       N          N          N
```

I'm at a loss for how to do that.

Comment: Do you only want to display 1 row "Bacon" or does the table contain multiple pers_name ?

Comment: I have multiple entries for bacon, I want just 1 row for bacon. I also have multiple entries for smith, brown, ect..

Comment: What about my answer?

Comment: You may wish to store dates within a DATE datatype, as per normal practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your `$rows` variable will looks after fetching results like this:

```
$rows = array(0 => array('pers_id' => 431, 'pers_name' => 'Bacon', 'pers_date' => '1/14/2013', 'pers_date_attend_ind' => 'N'),
              1 => array('pers_id' => 431, 'pers_name' => 'Bacon', 'pers_date' => '1/27/2013', 'pers_date_attend_ind' => 'N'),
              2 => array('pers_id' => 431, 'pers_name' => 'Bacon', 'pers_date' => '1/28/2013', 'pers_date_attend_ind' => 'N'),
              3 => array('pers_id' => 431, 'pers_name' => 'Bacon', 'pers_date' => '2/17/2013', 'pers_date_attend_ind' => 'N'),
        );
```

Then I played with this array to make it look like this:

```
Array
(
    [431] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bacon
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [1/14/2013] => N
                    [1/27/2013] => N
                    [1/28/2013] => N
                    [2/17/2013] => N
                )

        )

)
```

using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($rows as $value)
{
    $array[$value['pers_id']]['name'] = $value['pers_name'];
    $array[$value['pers_id']]['dates'][$value['pers_date']] = $value['pers_date_attend_ind'];
}
```

Now it looks much better for your table(s) preparation. I created a function what returns a table(s) as you set in your question based on this modified array.

```
function generate_table($array)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        $html .= '<table>'; // start table inside the loop. It will looks better due to each member may have different number of date count.
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        foreach($value['dates'] as $k => $v)
        {
            $html .= '<td>' . $k . '</td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $value['name'] . '</td>';
        foreach($value['dates'] as $v)
        {
            $html .= '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '</table>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

This function looks a bit nasty, but it works. It's on you to improve this function if you want.

### Live previews

- [Preview for single user](https://eval.in/191411)
- [Preview for multiple users](https://eval.in/191354)

### Preview of result

[image: Results...]

Comment: My page is this http://pastebin.com/x3m9DMPT    I'm getting "[error] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied       for foreach() in FollowUpMain.php on line 60"

Comment: Before `foreach` insert: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) $rows[] = $row;`. Also replace `$rows = mysql_query(...)` with `$query = mysql_query(...)` and also you shouldn't use `mysql_`, use `mysqli_` or PDO instead with prepared statements.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SiWz0XYe  - table     http://pastebin.com/rYVhzLxj  - exact php   - not working, but not getting an error, blank page

Comment: You forgot echo these tables. After function declaration (after last `}` and before `?>`) insert this line: `echo generate_table($array);`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple `SELECT` query to get all `pers_date` and `pers_date_attend_ind` for one person and limit it to three results only.

```
SELECT `pers_date`, `pers_date_attend_ind` FROM `table` WHERE `pers_id` = 431 ORDER BY `pers_date` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Then just fetch the results and print them with php.

Answer (score 0):

Unfotunately mysql doesn have magic function to transform values wich are variables to column names , But in your case you should have an extra column (`date_number` i have added it in demo) which count the number of dates added.

here is aproach to it:

```
    select `pers_name`,

    max(case when `date_number` = 1 then `pers_date_attend_ind` end) as date1,
    max(case when `date_number` = 2 then `pers_date_attend_ind` end) as date2,
    max(case when `date_number` = 3 then `pers_date_attend_ind` end) as date3,
    max(case when `date_number` = 4 then `pers_date_attend_ind` end) as date4
    from Table1
```

[**HERE demo to play with**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8dbe1/3)

Comment: What if there will be fifth record with next date?

Comment: Its up to him, if there is 5th date then he will add fifth select , Or he have to do it with triggers loop , this was an aproach answer.